# What's the right order to save an detached object graph in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am working on saving complex detached objects with the entity framework. I retrieve the objects from a web API and deserialize the json into c# objects.
A simplified version of a part of my entities look like this:

```
class Order{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    long Id {get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Billing")]
    long BillingId { get; set; }

    Address Billing { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Shipping")]
    long ShippingId { get; set; }

    Address Shipping{ get; set; }
}

class Address{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    long Id { get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("Country")]
    long CountryId { get; set; }

    Country Country { get; set; }
}

class Country{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    long Id { get; set;} 
}
```

I go through the object graph and try to determine which objects i have to insert and which just need to be updated. With code like the following(actual code runs with a generic function, i just wrote it all out to get a better hold of it):

```
Order order = restClient.Get<Order>(1);
using(var context = new MyContext()){
    if (order.Billing != null){
        if(order.Billing.Country != null){
                var dbBillingCountry = context.Set<Country>().Find(order.Billing.Country.Id);
                if(dbBillingCountry == null){
                    context.Set<Country>().Add(order.Billing.Country);
                }
                else{
                    context.Entry(dbBillingCountry).CurrentValues.SetValues(order.Billing.Country);
                    //order.Billing.Country = dbBillingCountry;
                    context.Entry(dbBillingCountry).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
        }

        var dbBilling = context.Set<Address>().Find(order.Billing.Id);
        if(dbBilling == null){
            context.Set<Address>().Add(order.Billing);
        }
        else{
            context.Entry(dbBilling).CurrentValues.SetValues(order.Billing);
            //order.Billing = dbBilling;
            context.Entry(dbBilling).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        //db.SaveChanges();
    }
    if (order.Shipping != null){
        if(order.Shipping.Country != null){
                var dbShippingCountry = context.Set<Country>().Find(order.Shipping.Country.Id);
                if(dbShippingCountry == null){
                    context.Set<Country>().Add(order.Shipping.Country);
                }
                else{
                    context.Entry(dbShippingCountry).CurrentValues.SetValues(order.Shipping.Country);
                    //order.Shipping.Country = dbShippingCountry;
                    context.Entry(dbShippingCountry).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
        }
        var dbShipping = context.Set<Address>().Find(order.Shipping.Id);
        if(dbShipping == null){
            context.Set<Address>().Add(order.Shipping);
        }
        else{
            context.Entry(dbShipping).CurrentValues.SetValues(order.Shipping);
            //order.Shipping = dbShipping;
            context.Entry(dbShipping).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        //db.SaveChanges();
    }
    var dbOrder = context.Set<Order>().Find(order.Id);
    if(dbOrder == null){
        context.Set<Order>().Add(order);
    }
    else{
        context.Entry(dbOrder).CurrentValues.SetValues(order);
        //order = dbOrder;
        context.Entry(dbOrder).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In the case where `order.Billing` is the same object/values as `order.Shipping`  in `context.SaveChanges()` i get an error because EF tries to insert the address and before that the country twice with the same key. 
I tried to set a reference back of the database/local entity which `contex.Find` returns, but that doesn't fix it.
How can i tell the context, that these are the same objects?

Comment: Check if `Order.Billing` is the same as `Order.Shipping` and do not insert them both.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I tried to do that by setting the state of the  entry to `EntityState.Modified` and also tried to set it to `EntityState.Detached`, but that results in the state `EntityState.Added` after i attach the order to the context in the end. It seems that all detached child entities will be automatically added to the DbContext.
Do you have a suggestion how i can accomplish that it i dont insert them both?

Comment: No do not set it modified, simply do not add it to the context. There is no point because they are the same. Add one of them and save it.

Comment: @CodingYoshi If i add the `order` before the child-objects of it. All of the child-objects will be automatically added to the context. They're all in the `Added` state. If i then try do determine if the object already exists in the context or database, i.e. with the `context.Addresses.Find` method. I get a error Message like: `Multiple entities were found in the Added state that match the given primary key values.`